# Bootstrap Tooltip / Popover Dismissal Causing HTML element to be hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason in one of my projects the following Bootstrap.js Tooltip/Popover code in the Tooltip.prototype.leave function is causing my icon to disappear (be set to display: none) upon dismissing the tip/popover.

```
if (!self.options.delay || !self.options.delay.hide) return self.hide()

self.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    if (self.hoverState == 'out') self.hide()
}, self.options.delay.hide)
```

I'm implementing the popover as recommended:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        console.log($j('.help-popover'));
        $j('.help-popover').popover({
            placement: 'top'
        });
    });
</script>

<a tabindex="0" class="help-popover glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Help" data-content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat sed."></a>
```

Some guesses I have as to the cause are that its related to the project also needing to use an old copy of Prototype.js and therefore also using js_noconflict.js, This is why in the html sample above you see the `$j` syntax representing jQuery.

I've already attempted replacing all `$` calls to `$j` calls in a local copy of the bootstrap.js without fixing the issue. Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Bootstrap.js line 1404 as below

```
//if (obj instanceof $.Event) {
    //  self.inState[obj.type == 'focusout' ? 'focus' : 'hover'] = false
    //}
```

To

```
//09-04-2016 Jay Bhavsar Changed condition if it is hover out then set instate as true
    //if (obj instanceof $.Event) {
    //  self.inState[obj.type == 'focusout' ? 'focus' : 'hover'] = false
    //}
    if (obj instanceof $.Event) {
        if (obj.type == 'focusout') {
            self.inState['focus'] = false;
        }
        else {
            self.inState['hover'] = true;
        }
    }
```

Basically it was setting "inState" to "false" so when hover out happened it was continuing on other code instead of returning. the continuing code was to set tooltip hide.